# React - TailwindCSS | Vertically and horizotally centered elements using display: flex disappears above the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile, tailwind-css

Context:

- I have a ReactJS App using Tailwind CSS.
- My body have two classes : `bg-black text-white`

This is the code of my "Sign up" page :

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen max-w-screen-lg mx-auto min-h-min">
    <div className="md:flex items-center justify-center w-full px-4">
        <div className="md:w-1/2 md:mb-0 mb-24">
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-white text-center">pongBSD</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="md:w-1/2 max-w-sm mx-auto">
            <div className="w-full">
                <a href="#" className="w-full block bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-600 to-slate-600 hover:from-slate-500 hover:to-slate-500 text-white text-center font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                    connect with 42
                </a>
            </div>
            <div className="w-full my-12 bg-gray-300 h-1"></div>
            <h1 className="text-xl font-bold text-white text-center mb-8">or sign up with email</h1>
            <form className="w-full">
                <div className="md:flex">
                    <div className="mb-6 md:mr-3">
                        <label className="block text-gray-500 font-bold mb-1 pr-4" for="inline-first-name">
                            first name
                        </label>
                        <input className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 placeholder:appearance-none" id="inline-first-name" type="text" placeholder="John" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb-6 md:ml-3">
                        <label className="block text-gray-500 font-bold mb-1 pr-4" for="inline-last-name">
                            last name
                        </label>
                        <input className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 placeholder:appearance-none" id="inline-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Doe" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label className="block text-gray-500 font-bold mb-1 pr-4" for="inline-username">
                        username
                    </label>
                    <input className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 placeholder:appearance-none" id="inline-username" type="text" placeholder="owt-ytrof" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label className="block text-gray-500 font-bold mb-1 pr-4" for="inline-email">
                        email
                    </label>
                    <input className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500 placeholder:appearance-none" id="inline-email" type="email" placeholder="email@example.com" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-12">
                    <label className="block text-gray-500 font-bold mb-1 pr-4" for="inline-password">
                        password
                    </label>
                    <input className="bg-gray-200 appearance-none border-2 border-gray-200 rounded w-full py-2 px-4 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-indigo-500" id="inline-password" type="password" placeholder="********" />
                </div>
                <button className="w-full bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-600 to-purple-600 hover:from-indigo-500 hover:to-purple-500 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" type="button">
                    sign up
                </button>
                <div className="text-white text-xs mt-3 text-center">
                    already registered?
                    <br />
                    <a href="#" className="underline hover:text-green-600">
                        go to the login page
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- It looks like this on small screens : https://ibb.co/F0cx4T9
- From the medium size screens it looks like this: https://ibb.co/3f7MycL
- But i created these images using a 2K computer screen.
  If i am on a smartphone the pongBSD text disappear behind the web browser interface : https://ibb.co/k254WHz

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to prevent the text to go up higher than the beginning of the page. Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

I tried to set margin top, position fixed...

Comment: Can't you just add `pt-24` to the parent div of the `h1`? So: `<div class="md:w-1/2 md:mb-0 mb-24 pt-24"><h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-white text-center">pongBSD</h1></div>`

Comment: It just lowers the content a bit but the text still doesn't appear, there is no other solution than adding a big margin on top for smartphones?

Comment: Because i can fix it by adding `md:py-0 pt-96` to the second div from the top.
But i dont know if it is the good way to fix it